# Equality case of triangle inequality with functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f, g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\left|f(x) + g(x)\right| = \left|f(x)\right| + \left|g(x)\right|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then must $f = cg$ for some $c \gt 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same sign  for all $x$. Then your equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=x^4$. $f+g$ is always positive, and so are $f$ and $g$. So the equality holds, but your condition is false.

Comment: noted. What's the point that I am missing?

Comment: Functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ generally means that the range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$; need not be all of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct. Expanding on Andre's answer... the condition you want is
$$f(x) g(x) \ge 0$$